# MAP estimation for conditional probability

Tags: probability, statistics, bayesian

I'm studying bayesian estimation of model parameters and i noticed in several ML books (Deep Learning Goodfellow, ML a probabilistic perspective K. Murphy) that they used the bayesian rule in the following way:
$$
    p(\theta \mid X, y) \propto p(y \mid X, \theta) \cdot p(\theta)
$$
Which one then used to deriving MAP estimate:
$$
   \theta _{MAP} = \operatorname {argmax} \limits_{\theta} \log p(y \mid X , \theta) \cdot p(\theta)
$$

On the other hand, the Bayes rule formally gives the next equation for this case:
$$
   p(\theta \mid X, y) = \dfrac{p(y \mid X, \theta) \cdot p(\theta \mid X)}{p(y \mid X)}
$$

So i don't understand why they ignore the conditioning on $X$, it seems to me that they suppose that $\theta$ and $X$ independent? But why?

P.S.
I found similar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3964284/map-estimation-for-discriminative-models) was asked 2 years ago but this one remained unanswered :(

[MAP = maximum *a posteriori*, in case anyone was wondering. —Brian Tung]

Comment: There may be a better way to show it but one can think of $p(\theta |X)$ in the equality as $ \frac{P(\theta~ \cap ~X)}{P(X)}$.  Now the fact that it's proportional to $P(\theta)$ hopefully makes more sense because intersecting with $X$ doesn't change the fact that it's proportional to $P(\theta)$ because, as $P(\theta)$ increases, the probability of the intersection increases.

Comment: and similarly,  as $P(\theta)$ decreases, the probability of the intersection decreases.

Comment: @markleeds may we take the parameters with the largest density but which doesn’t have intersection with X then ?

Comment: I'm not clear on your question in the comment but I'll try to say what my thinking is in a different way. You are wondering why the proportional case can just say proportional to $P(\theta)$ rather than use the $P(\theta|X)$ from the equality. I am saying that that can be done because $P(\theta|X)$ is proportional to $P(\theta)$. So, since it's proportional, it can be replaced by $P(\theta)$. So, nothing to do with largest density. That's just my thinking. Maybe there are better answers ?

Comment: @markleeds as i understand when you say "proportional" it means that when $p(\theta)$ increases then $p(\theta \cap X)$ increases, but $p(\theta)$ could change only if $\theta$ changes. Formally $p(\theta \in B_1 \cap X \in B_2) = \mathbb{P}(\theta^{-1}(B_1) \cap X^{-1}(B_2))$ where $B_1, B_2$ are some Borel sets, but if we change $\theta$ then set $\theta^{-1}(B_1)$ could change drastically and may have even $\emptyset$ intersection with $X^{-1}(B_2)$ although the density of parameters $p(\theta)$ may become larger then before

Comment: I don't agree with the idea that conditioning can be dropped because of some proportionality that comes from the definition of conditional probability. Proportionality is used in these texts because the marginal likelihood is just a normalizing constant. But if you include it, you have equality: $p(\theta | X, y) = \frac{p(y|X, \theta) p(\theta)}{p(y|X)}$. You won't be able to derive why the conditioning can be dropped as it's an assumption.

Comment: Also, I can see that you are trying to reason very formally about this by using the measure-theoretic formulation of probability theory, writing out the pre-images of your R.Vs and the corresponding Borel sets. While it's good to have a solid grasp of probability theory, this level of rigour is dropped when doing statistical learning / ML. It's like doing calculus and trying to reason about it through Lebesgue measures and integrals. Texts like Murphy, Bishop, Goodfellow don't directly work with measure theoretic probability, they just acknowledge it as a foundation.

Comment: Thanks Marks and Something Faceless. I think my reasoning is correct but I'm not sure how to be more rigorous in my statement in order to prove it more formally. Maybe someone else will chime in. Thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The independence of $\theta$ given $X$ is indeed an assumption that's very common in Bayesian inference.

It comes from the fact that $p(\theta)$ expresses the prior information about the parameters of your model. These are essentially your model assumptions, which are independent of whatever data you choose to show your model.

You can think of it like this: you use MAP instead of MLE to derive the optimal parameters of your model because you believe that the prior information you have about these parameters based on the structure of your problem will help give more sensible answers (otherwise you could just impose a uniform prior where any parameter value is equally likely which would be equivalent to doing MLE).

So even though Bayes rule would tell you to condition everything on $X$, because of the way the problem is set up, the choice of priors comes before anything else.

The priors you place on your parameters have a crucial effect on the predictive power of your model. Indeed if your prior excludes the possibility of some parameter values by giving them zero weight, you won't be able to obtain them through this kind of inference, regardless of how well they explain the observed data through the likelihood. Therefore, it is really important to select sensible priors.

The bottom line is, your prior is independent of your inputs and that is why you are able to drop the conditioning on $X$. Hopefully the above gives you some intuition as to why this is the case.

Comment: I am a little confused by the fact that when we make a MAP estimate, we want to deduce the parameters $\theta$ based on the observations X and y that came in, but when formulating a MAP estimate, we say that the parameters $\theta$ and X are independent

Comment: You want to deduce the parameters given the observations AND your prior beliefs. You can make no observations, yet you will still have a distribution over the parameters, which is expressed through your prior. Showing your model more data doesn't affect what you originally thought about the problem and the possible solutions you decided to place a higher weight on, based on the specifics of your problem. That's why they are independent.

Comment: [Dmarks](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1198800/dmarks) could you please clarify what then changes when we get new observations? Ok, our prior beliefs about the parameters remains the same, but when we get new observations we need to find parameters that maximizing $p(\theta \mid X, y)$, how we can do that if our parameters are independent of data?

Comment: The posterior $p(\theta | X, y)$ is not independent of the observations $X$. The key is that the dependence comes from the likelihood term $p(y|X, \theta)$ but not the prior $p(\theta|X)$ which allows us to write it as $p(\theta)$.  When data comes in, the posterior over parameters is updated according to how well the data is explained by particular choices of parameters (likelihood) as well as our prior distribution over these parameters. If you get even more observations, your posterior will now become your prior, as this now expresses your current belief about the parameters.

Comment: Very thanks, I think I see what you mean

Answer (score 0):

You can add to the list of books that make this assumption Rasmussen's *Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning*.

This seems to be a very recurrent question on this site ... In addition to the similar question you raised in your post, we can also mention (1) https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/584279/is-there-an-implicit-independence-assumption-in-bayesian-inference-between-x-and ; (2) [Independence of the data and the parameter in Machine Learning](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1882178/independence-of-the-data-and-the-parameter-in-machine-learning) or even (3) [Bayesian Linear Regression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2988860/bayesian-linear-regression)

Some answers seem to treat the prior distribution as a random variable, then assert the independence between this random variable and X. Treating distributions of variables as random variables is, of course, a common practice, but that's not what we're doing here.
In the derivation reported here, it is the independence between X and $\theta$ itself that is asserted, not the independance between X and the distribution of your a priori beliefs about $\theta$.

I guess that an answer that somehow encompasses Dmarks' intuition and (1)'s comments on the fixity of X is that the source of randomness that makes $\theta$ random is not the same as the source of randomness that determines which inputs are observed.

X can be considered random in the sense that samples are drawn at random from a dataset (some even consider it non-random, but if you come from ML you probably want to think of it as stochastic). On the other hand, $\theta$ is random for Bayesian reasons, whatever your interpretation of Bayesianity (model your subjective belief, or the uncertainty about the world from which the observed experience comes from among a collection of competing worlds ...), and can additionally model a source of uncertainty intrinsic to the interactions between X and y (additive noise ...) that we try to imitate with our parameters, but which will be entirely taken care of by y and not by X in the way we look at the problem. I suppose you could think of it as a product measurable space between *Sampling* and *(Uncertainty & Inner randomness)*, and X varies only according to the first.